# Calculating Min, Max and Average in Datetime string List in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

```
Insert Into Heartbeat values
( 1 ,'3/20/2017 07:05'),
( 1 ,'3/20/2017 07:15'),
( 1 ,'3/20/2017 07:35'),
( 1 ,'3/20/2017 07:55'),
( 2 ,'3/20/2017 07:11'),
( 2 ,'3/20/2017 07:19'),
( 2 ,'3/20/2017 07:45'),
( 2 ,'3/20/2017 07:58')

;with cte as (
        Select SensorID
              ,MinDT        = Min(DatetimeInformation)
              ,MaxDT        = Max(DatetimeInformation)
        From  @YourTable
        Group By SensorID
                ,Convert(date,DatetimeInformation)
                ,DatePart(HOUR,DatetimeInformation)
)
Select SensorID
      ,Date  = Convert(date,MinDT)
      ,TimeDuration = Format(MinDT,'htt')+ ' - ' + Format(DateAdd(HOUR,1,minDT),'htt')
      ,DateTimeInformationList = Stuff((Select ', ' +Format(DatetimeInformation,'M/dd/yyyy h:mm') 
                                         From  HeartBeat
                                         Where SensorID=A.SensorID 
                                           and DatetimeInformation between A.MinDT and A.MaxDT  
                                         Order By DatetimeInformation 
                                         For XML Path ('')
                                       ),1,2,'')
 from  cte A
```

Returns

```
Date         TimeDuration   DateTimeInformationList
1           2017-03-20   7AM - 8AM      3/20/2017 7:05, 3/20/2017 7:15, 3/20/2017 7:35, 3/20/2017 7:55
2           2017-03-20   7AM - 8AM      3/20/2017 7:11, 3/20/2017 7:19, 3/20/2017 7:45, 3/20/2017 7:58
```

I was able to get help to group the Datetimeinformation per hour which is above query.
I need to get the Average time gap(minutes or seconds) for all the DatetimeInformationList for that TimeDuration (7AM to 8AM)

Comment: When i try to insert another 2 rows with ( 1 ,'3/20/2017 08:05') , ( 1 ,'3/20/2017 08:15') then the Sensor ID 1 should have 2 rows, one with 7AM to 8AM and another 8AM to 9AM and average should be for 7AM to 8AM seperately and 8AM to 9AM seperately. But the below answered  query is picking the all the dates for SensorID 1 and calculates the average. It should calculate based on Time Interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modification of your CTE that appears to do what you are looking for.

```
;with cte as (
    Select h1.SensorID
        ,MinDT        = Min(h1.DatetimeInformation)
        ,MaxDT        = Max(h2.DatetimeInformation)
        ,AvgInterval    = Avg(datediff(second, h1.DateTimeInformation, h2.DateTimeInformation))
    From  #HeartBeat h1
    INNER JOIN #Heartbeat h2
        ON h1.SensorID = h2.SensorID
    WHERE h2.DateTimeInformation = (
        SELECT min(dateTimeInformation)
        FROM #Heartbeat h3
        WHERE h3.SensorID = h1.SensorID
            AND h3.DateTimeInformation > h1.DateTimeInformation
        )
    Group By h1.SensorID
            ,Convert(date,h1.DatetimeInformation)
            ,DatePart(HOUR,h1.DatetimeInformation)
)
Select A.SensorID
    ,Date  = Convert(date,MinDT)
    ,TimeDuration = Format(MinDT,'htt')+ ' - ' + Format(DateAdd(HOUR,1,minDT),'htt')
    ,DateTimeInformationList = Stuff((Select ', ' +Format(DatetimeInformation,'M/dd/yyyy h:mm') 
                                    From  #HeartBeat
                                    Where SensorID=A.SensorID 
                                        and DatetimeInformation between A.MinDT and A.MaxDT  
                                    Order By DatetimeInformation 
                                    For XML Path ('')
                                ),1,2,'')
    ,AverageInterval = Cast(Cast(AvgInterval / 60 as int) As varchar(2)) + ':' + Cast(AvgInterval % 60 AS varchar(2))
```

from  cte A

The output:

```
SensorID    Date    TimeDuration    DateTimeInformationList                                     AverageInterval
1       2017-03-20  7AM - 8AM   3/20/2017 7:05, 3/20/2017 7:15, 3/20/2017 7:35, 3/20/2017 7:55  16:40
2       2017-03-20  7AM - 8AM   3/20/2017 7:11, 3/20/2017 7:19, 3/20/2017 7:45, 3/20/2017 7:58  15:40
```

Comment: NOTE: I used a #temp table named #Heartbeat for testing purposes.

Comment: When i try to insert another 2 rows with ( 1 ,'3/20/2017 08:05') , ( 1 ,'3/20/2017 08:15') then the Sensor ID 1 should have 2 rows, one with 7AM to 8AM and another 8AM to 9AM and average should be for 7AM to 8AM seperately and 8AM to 9AM seperately. But the above query is picking the all the dates for SensorID 1 and calculates the average. It should calculate based on Time Interval.